# Ansible-Execute a last mandatory role in the playbook even though any previous roles in the execution flow fails

Tags: ansible

I have ansible playbook something like this

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        build_date_time: "{{ ansible_date_time }}"

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    role: Appvariables
    base_image_tag: Base
  roles:
    - role: begin-building-ami

- hosts: just_created
  remote_user:  "{{ default_user }}"
  vars:
    role: AppName
  roles:
    - { role: role1, become: yes }
    - role: role2
    - { role: role3, become: yes }
    - { role: role4, become: yes }
    - { role: role5, become: yes }

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    role: Appname
    ansible_date_time: "{{ build_date_time }}"
  roles:
    - finish-building-ami
```

Here in this case we have a situation to execute the finish-building-ami role where we terminate the instance after baking the ami. If any reason any of the previous role1-role5 fails in the flow fails It stops the playbook and we have the failed instance which we needed to terminate automatically.Right now we are going and terminating it manually if it fails.

So needed to run finish-building-ami(mandatory role where we stop the instance and take ami and terminate the instance at last ) if even any of the role1-role5 fails in the above mentioned playbook.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation on [Ansible blocks and exception handling](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#error-handling).

Comment: @larsks I tried use blocks and blocks can be used at task level.Ideally in our scenario we use tasks inside the role. But based on my understanding and after trying it out block cannot used here in the abpve mentioned code at the playbook level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your existing play to use `import_role` or `include_role` tasks instead of the `roles` section. This allows you to use blocks:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - block:
        - import_role:
            name: role1

        - import_role:
            name: role2
          become: true

        - import_role:
            name: role3
      rescue:
        - set_fact:
            role_failed: true

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: This task runs after our roles.
```

Comment: I changed my code my something like this. i am trying to execute one role based on role_failed variable but its not resolving                                                          
- hosts: just_created
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - block:
        - import_role:
            name: role1

        - import_role:
            name: role2
          become: true
      rescue:
        - set_fact:
            role_failed: true

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - import_role:
        name: role_name
      when: role_failed

Comment: Since set_facts are hosts_specific i could not resolve the role_failed variable accross the hosts. Any alternative to these in ansible. @larsks

Comment: You can access facts for other hosts via the `hostvars` variable.  So you can examine `hostvars[hostname].role_failed` for all your hosts, for example.  [Docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables). You may also be able to [delegate](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html) the `set_fact` task to a specific host (e.g., `localhost`) so you only need to check for it in one place.

Comment: Thanks let me try this

Comment: would it be possible to wrap multiple tasks in inside of `-block` and `rescue` instead ?

Comment: This example *is* wrapping multiple tasks inside of a `block` (there are three `import_role` tasks inside the `block`). If there's something in particular you're trying to accomplish, it might be easiest to open a new question.